# "no main manifest attribute" after uncompressing and recompressing jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar, manifest

I have a Spring Boot jar built by `mvn package`. If I run `java -jar`, it works.

If I uncompress and recompress it, without changing the contents, it stops working.

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
jar -xf ../old.jar
tar -cf ../new.jar *
cd ..
java -jar old.jar # works
java -jar new.jar

no main manifest attribute, in new.jar
```

How do I rebuild the jar from its extracted contents, preserving the manifest and all other metadata it contains?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to specify the manifest directly

```
jar cfm foo.jar path/to/manifest *
```